# perception_pcl error with flann

Tags: ros, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting an error as if it doesn't know about flann when I

```
rosmake perception_pcl --rosdep-install
```

The error is:

```
~/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/include/pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h:44:27: error: flann/flann.hpp: No such file or directory
```

It's followed up by a series of similar complaints from other lines in the .h file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9275/perception_pcl-error-with-flann/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-04**:
More detail:v. 0.10.0 of perception_pcl and perception_pcl_addons/trunk/pcl_visualization at revision 36356.

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-03**:
Diamondback on Mac OS X 10.6.6. I had previously gotten perception_pcl running and just got this error with the latest upgrade to diamondback which I installed via rosinstall and the url for the full desktop version. flann installs just fine, and rospack find finds it perfectly too.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-03**:
Can you update your post to include how you installed ROS and perception_pcl? Are you trying to use cturtle/diamondback/unstable? What is the output of `rospack find flann`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did another rosinstall and got the latest build of perception_pcl which seems to work. I'm not sure what the problem was though.

flann still has the name_install_tool section commented out; I'm not sure why since it's necessary to have the correct location for libflann_cpp or , so I think you have to do it manually if the Makefile doesn't. So my Makefile has for that:

```
if [ `uname` = Darwin ]; then \
    install_name_tool -id `rospack find flann`/lib/libflann_cpp.1.6.dylib lib/libflann_cpp.1.6.7.dylib; \
fi
```

Note that you have to fix the whole path. Can somebody confirm and fix this in svn? I see it's still in flann 1.6.8.

Also I removed all refs to lib64 in the flann manifest.xml. pcl_ros still refers to it and complains in the log file, but it doesn't have any effect that I have so far observed on pcd_viewer. Not sure about other things. Here's what my manifest.xml for flann has in the  section (I removed the angle brackets which were affecting display of the code):

```
cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -lflann_cpp -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5"
```

Again if flann isn't actually using a lib64 directory, this should be removed from the manifest.xml in svn.

---

Originally posted by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) with karma: 255 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-08**:
to get a patch applied to source code please open a ticket.